# Socket.IO triggering request every second

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I wonder how to stop socketio to trigger request every second. Here is my back and front end code:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log(`a user connected`)
        socket.on('join', (data) => {
            socket.broadcast.emit(
                'player action',
                `${data.name} has join the table`
            )
            console.log('user', `${data.name} has joined `)
            console.log('data player: ', data)
        })
        socket.on('quit', (data) => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('player action', `${data.name} has left`)
            console.log(`user ${data.name} has left`)
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('a user quit')
        })
    })
```

on the client side there is only that:

```
const socket = io()
```

Comment: are you talking about those `StatusCode: 101` requests? This is needed and wanted in `socket.io` since you want the server to be able to push events to the client by itself (usually this is not possible because the client has to ask the server via http request in order to get any backend information)

Comment: No i'm not, i'm actuallly talkin about statusCode 200 that trigger every sec. I do not know if it's natural behavior. And i m talking about a lot more per second if i add more event with socket io

Comment: Can you provide some more information or a screenshot of the event that is getting triggered?

Comment: What's showing in your server log (from the console.logs)?  Is it showing 'a user connected' every second?  If not, then  you're not connecting properly.  What's the url of your client page?  The url of the requests you're seeing?  Looking at [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/) I would say the client is trying to find the server, but the default uses window.location, so you probably need to specify in your client that you want to connect to '/socket.io', or change the path in your server...

Comment: I gess i just fixed it by specifying the client url in io like this
`const socket = io(`${url}`, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
})`

Thanks anyway guys. Sorry for missing screenshots i m new stackoverflow user, still working out to find how it works.